# How to select Multiple values on asp dropdownlist comming from a table and retrieve those values

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I have a dropdownlist. The values are populated into the dropdownlist using entity framework. The issue is I am unable to select multiple values and get the selected value.  Below is my current code.The rid value is returning 'NULL'

Dropdownlist Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <label>users:</label>
    <asp:DropDownList  id="ddlusers"  runat="server" onchange="selectUserToNode(this)" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Function:

```
function selectUserToNode(dlist) {
    var nid = $('#NId').val();
    var rid = document.getElementById("ddlusers");
    // var rid= $('#ddlroles option:selected').text()
    // var rid = $('#ddlroles').val();
    var strUser = rid.options[rid.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. You are passing the ddlusers object on the change event to the function yet you are not using it to select the options. What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I don't know if this is your full problem, but your DropDownList is is ddlusers, but in your javascript function you are looking for ddlroles.

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake while copying code over here. I modified my code. I am trying to get the selected value in the dropdown list to be saved into rid. I might be single or multiple values

Comment: I thought that the ID value on client side was changed by when using server generated elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By giving the ClientIDMode = "static" on the html declaration it solved my issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
<label>users:</label>
<asp:DropDownList  id="ddlusers"  runat="server" onchange="selectUserToNode(this)" SelectionMode="Multiple" ClientIDMode = "static"></asp:DropDownList>
```